# Socket in AsyncTask processes incoming data too slow

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, threadpool

I've got a problem with my code structure, it works fine but it takes 150-200 ms to process data and it will definitely increase with the size of my database. I was thinking about processing incoming data in a Thread but it could work out. Here is the asynctask:

```
public class IncomingData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    public BufferedReader input;
    public String read = null;

    public IncomingData() {
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            while (input.ready()) {
                read = input.readLine();

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return read;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(final String input) {

        if (input != null) {
            InputStreamTokenizer(input);    
        }
        new IncomingData().execute();
    }
}
```

So basicly i'm saying that the function InputStreamTokenizer takes 200+ ms to finish, just after that i can read new incoming lines.
Any idea how could i make a thread or anything of it?
Thanks,

Comment: you already have it all in a thread. doInBackground does just that

Comment: This is very strange code. You read a line or more? What the tokeniser does with the read is invisible. Why rename read to input? Very confusing. After one, two or how much lines you start another asynctask and create a new stream. Why, why, why? What would a Thread do better than an AsyncTask i wonder. Just put all code in doInBackground. Process every line in a loop.

Comment: Chillz chillz :)) After the socket is created and is connected i open the asynctask, in the background it reads one line input then it gives to postExecute where the InputStreamTokenizer processes it. It doesn't really matter what it does, it just take a lot of time because there are a lot of database queries.

I just want a thread that does the inputstremtokenisering so the AsyncTask can go back reading socket inputs.

Comment: if inputStreamTokenizer takes .2secs it should be in doinbackground.  Also IDK if you should not be starting a new asynctask from it self.  Perhaps it should just return because you would have already read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) instead execute()